# Making quote renewenvironment have ttfamily font

Tags: environments, line-spacing, typewriter, setspace

I want my `quote` environment

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\@ldquote=\quote
\let\@ldendquote=\endquote
\renewenvironment{quote}
   {\@ldquote\setlength{\baselineskip\ttfamily}{\singlebaselineskip}}
   {\@ldendquote}

\begin{document}

Some text.
\begin{quote}
A quotation.
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

To appear with `\tttext` or `\ttfamily` whichever one is supposed to use in environments.

So that

\begin{quote}
...
\end{quote}

appears as \tttext{...}.

How does one achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the code snippets you've posted, it would appear to be the case that you not only want to use a monospaced font in the `quote` environment, but also that you wish to use single-spacing in these environments. If that's the case, I suggest you include the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox,setspace}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\ttfamily\raggedright\frenchspacing\setstretch{1.0}}
```

A full MWE (mininum working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,setspace,lipsum}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\ttfamily\raggedright\frenchspacing\setstretch{1.0}}

\doublespacing % or "\onehalfspacing"?

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] % filler text
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[2] % more filler text
\end{quote}
\lipsum[3] % still more filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer helped me format all quotes in my document. I did not know about `\AtBeginEnvironment{}` and it helped me get pandoc to format all blockquotes in my document (I have a double-spaced document that I wanted blockquotes formatted with single-spaced lines and smaller font). I simply added this to my pandoc YAML block:
`header-includes: '\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\setstretch{1.0}\small}'`